# Using NFC within an adapter

Tags: android, nfc, listview-adapter

Hi so I am using a custom adapter to populate a ListView of check boxes. The main activity is a fragment (not an activity). 
The check boxes each have names and ID, eg Shells - 12345. What I am trying to do is when the screen loads and the users scans a RFID tag, it reads the tag ID eg 12345, and the check boxes get selected if their ID matches.
How can I achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Edit:
I have used nfc in my log in section like so:

```
public class loginPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd ");
    NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private String serialId = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "NFC NOT supported on this devices!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } else if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "NFC NOT Enabled!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        //buttonbypass
        Button toMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_bypass);
        toMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(loginPage.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) ||
                NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            if (tag != null) {
                ((GlobalData) getApplication()).setUserTag(tag);
                String serialID = ((GlobalData) this.getApplication()).getUserID();
                if(serialID.equalsIgnoreCase("04950f4ae53f80")){
                    String jobPath = "USERS/04950F4AE53F80/LOGTIME/";
                    final DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(jobPath);
                   // LogClass logClass = new LogClass(date.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()), time.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()),"");
                   // myRef.child(date.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())).setValue(logClass);

                    Intent goToConfirm = new Intent(this, confirmLogin.class);
                    startActivity(goToConfirm);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"This is not an employee!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i tried to implement this within my adapter like so:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JobOverviewResourceClass> {

    private ArrayList<JobOverviewResourceClass> JobResourcesclass;
    //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, new Intent(getContext(), getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    int i = 1;
    String resourceID;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<JobOverviewResourceClass> JobResourcesclass) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, JobResourcesclass);
        this.JobResourcesclass = new ArrayList<>();
        this.JobResourcesclass.addAll(JobResourcesclass);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        TextView amnt;
        CheckBox name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.job_overview_resource_checks, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Resource_checkBox);
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Resource_checkBox_Text);
            holder.amnt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Resource_checkBox_amount_Text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    JobOverviewResourceClass resource = (JobOverviewResourceClass) cb.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                                    " is " + cb.isChecked(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    final Integer neededquant = resource.getmRESQUANTITY();
                    final String shelfresname = resource.getShelfresneeded();
                    //final Integer shelfquant =;
                    final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("RESOURCES/INVENTORY");
                    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()
                                    ) {
                                ResourceInventoryClass rcs = data.getValue(ResourceInventoryClass.class);
                                String key = data.getKey();
                                resourceID = rcs.ID;
                                nfcStuff();
                                if (i == 0) {
                                    if (rcs.NAME.equals(shelfresname)) {
                                        final Integer shelfquant = rcs.getmQUANTITY();
                                        i++;
                                        final Integer NewShelfQuantity = shelfquant - neededquant;
                                        ref.child(key).child("QUANTITY").setValue(NewShelfQuantity);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.e("Chat", "The read failed: " + databaseError.getDetails());
                        }
                    });
                    resource.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    //END OF ONCLICK ACTIVITY
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        JobOverviewResourceClass resource = JobResourcesclass.get(position);
        holder.code.setText(resource.getmName());
        String xx = Integer.toString(resource.getmRESQUANTITY());
        holder.amnt.setText("     x " + xx);
        holder.name.setChecked(resource.isSelected());
        holder.name.setTag(resource);
        return convertView;

    }


    public void nfcStuff() {
        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(getContext());
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getContext(), 0, new Intent(getContext(), getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }

    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) ||
                NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            if (tag != null) {
                String serialID = ((GlobalData) this.getContext()).getUserID();
                if (serialID.equalsIgnoreCase(resourceID)) {
                    i = 0;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This is not a resource!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this doesnt work as when i scanned the tag it brings up a list of apps.and does not check the box

Comment: Please specify what you tried, and where you are stuck. Please read [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have edited to include what i have done so far. Still trying to figure it out

Comment: added my adapter so far